# Automatically replace space with a non-breaking space after certain words

Tags: microsoft-word, autocorrect

I'm trying to use Word's AutoCorrect feature to replace the space after certain words with a non-breaking space. I tried adding the pattern "theword " in the Replace field, but it refuses to autocorrect a pattern that ends with a space (the Add button becomes disabled). If I use the word alone, I get two spaces, one non-breaking and one regular space.

Is there a better way to do this?

Background: in Arabic, the word "and" is a single letter (و), and it's visually unpleasing to have it alone at the end of a line. I currently use Find and Replace to replace them, but I'm looking for a way for Word automatically add the non-breaking space.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you're using Microsoft Word - which version?

In more recent versions you can edit the auto-correct options by going to ***File > Options > Proofing > Autocorrect Options...***
In the replace box add the word you wish to replace (in this case "and") and in the next box the same word followed by the non-breaking space (shortcut is ctrl+shift+space)
Make sure ***plain text*** is selected, click ***add***, and you're done!

There should be similar options available in older versions and in other word processing software.

Comment: I'm using Word 2010. I already tried that, and I mentioned in my question that "it refuses to autocorrect a pattern that ends with a space (the Add button becomes disabled)".

Comment: Sorry I missed that!

Comment: I can't see another way other than find/replace, though you could try a text expansion utility.